# Toolbar - application keeps stopping

Tags: java, android-studio

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"

    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is my activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is my MainActivity:

```
package com.example.exercise1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;


import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    }
}
```

I do not receive any information about the error, everything compiles without any problems, but the application eventually does not start and I receive a message saying that: application has stopped. What should I do to make the application run?

Answer (score 0):

In your java file, you imported the androidx library's Toolbar, in contrast with your layout's xml file that declared the android support library toolbar.
Delete the Toolbar's import statement in your java file and replace it with the support library Toolbar.

Comment: But when i try android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar, i have communicate that: Cannot resolve symbol 'v7'.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace this line in your layout XML file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

With this line

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

Always make sure to use the same library in the both files, Layout and class activity.

Comment: I have changed, unfortunately I am still receiving the message that: application has stopped.